# make reports "command not found" for an executable on my $PATH

Tags: bash, shell, unix, makefile

I'm working on a project that requires me to convert a c++ program (prog1.cpp) to a unix text file. I'm using the command

```
dos2unix prog1.cpp
```

However, the files that my     makefile makes aren't working as they should. make all is supposed to make an executable file hantow which is does, but upon executing hantow the shell reads:

```
-bash: hantow: command not found
```

My code is okay, no errors there. I can see there is a file called hantow in the directory and I've already ran

```
chmod 755 hantow
```

I wanted to ask if that's the only step you're supposed to take ie.dos2unix or are there any followup commands as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "the files that my makefile makes aren't working as they should"? Are they not compiling? Can you give any specific errors?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question.

Comment: Did you run `./hantow` in the same directory? If you just type `hantow`, bash will not look in the current directory, only in the $PATH (usually system programs only). I've made that mistake before...

Comment: My home directory is already added in PATH. So I was only doing hantow.

Comment: check that the hantow file that you see in your home directory is the one that is built by your make.  ls -l to check the time on it.   It may have come from the system you transfered the files from and is not a valid executable.

Comment: Is this a question about compiling code, or a question about running an executable, or a question about converting line endings in source code? It can't be all three at once...

Comment: I've renamed the question to make it describe the problem that @Laura seems to be having more precisely. Laura, the direct answer to your question is no, you should not need to run any followup commands after `dos2unix`, and the problem you're having is almost certainly something to do with how the Makefile and your build environment are organized rather than the problem of converting DOS text files to Unix.

Comment: If you put `echo "$PATH"` in the Makefile just before the command, do you see what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

well, text-files are pretty universal with one big (or minor) issue: line-endings.

traditionally, text files use different line-endings on differents systems:

- `CRLF` on W32
- `LF` on Un*x
- `CR` on MacOS

Luckily Apple switched to the proper Un*x line-endings when they moved to *OSX* (a while ago). So these days you will only find two different line-endings.

In the meantime, virtually *any* decent text-editor will handle text-files of any line-ending convention (I think the big exception is `notepad.exe` which still can only handle `CRLF`).
Also any `C`/`C++` compiler will not care at all about the actual line-ending.

So there is no real *need* to convert a "c++ program to unix text file".

OTOH, I still prefer working with native line-endings whenever possible, and `dos2unix` is a perfect tool for that. (though modern VCSs will automatically handle line-ending conversion for you, so there is less demand for `dos2unix` these days).

Finally: your problems with `hantow` are not related to this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question: `dos2unix` should usually be enough to convert the line endings of a file from `CRLF` to `LF`.  There may be other reasons that the code does not execute, for example if the code uses some other OS-specific functions that are not available in your environment.  Also make sure that your Makefile and other input files have the correct line endings.  You can call `file` on the file, to see whether it outputs something like `..., with CRLF line terminators`, in which case you might want to run `dos2unix` on them, too.